# Using on Activity in Android to draw multiple UI's

Tags: android, user-interface

I would like to know if it is wise/possible to have one activity that displays multiple different UI elements dynamically in a single layout?

So I want to have a single activity that loads a blank layout and then from code I add various UI elements such as buttons, text views etc. Then when a button is pressed, for that layout to clear and then from code draw the next set of UI elements on that same layout and so on and so forth?

Or would it be better to have multiple xml layout files and just inflate them each time I want to use a different layout, so then not create them from code?

Hope that makes sense.

Thanks,
Wihan

Comment: You can have a single Activity and then load a different Fragment inside it, from time to time.

Answer (score 2):

You should look into Fragments.
Activities are not intended to do what you would like them to do.

Instead you use one Activity and add a Fragment(s). Those Fragments can then be dynamically switched via code.

Take a tour => http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html

Comment: Hi.Thanks for the reply, I have gone over the link and some Fragment examples, but I fail to see exactly how it will be better to use Fragments for this? My layout of the fragment/UI will not be determined at compile time, all the UI elements will be generated from code, wiped and a different set will be generated?

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is very much possible. But Android xml layouts give a very easy way to use and manage different views. You could add views to ViewGroup and clear the ViewGroup.

I would also suggest using Fragments . This could be dynamically added and replaced.